# Clarification about a point of a jls

Tags: java, try-with-resources

Directly from this [jls](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3):

> A try-with-resources statement with a ResourceSpecification clause
>   that declares multiple resources is treated as if it were multiple
>   try-with-resources statements, each of which has a
>   ResourceSpecification clause that declares a single Resource. When a
>   try-with-resources statement with n Resources (n > 1) is translated,
>   the result is a try-with-resources statement with n-1 Resources. After
>   n such translations, there are n nested try-catch-finally statements,
>   and the overall translation is complete.

To me it's note very clear the last part of the above-quoted statement. Why if I have declared n resources then as they say `the result is a try-with-resources statement with n-1 Resources`?

Why not with n Resources?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is more-or-less explained in [Better Resource Management with Java SE 7: Beyond Syntactic Sugar](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/trywithresources-401775.html#nb3). Take this snippet, for example:

```
try(
    FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(input);
    FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(output);
    GZIPOutputStream out = new GZIPOutputStream(fout)
) {
    // ... do work
}
```

That would be equivalent to the following:

```
FileInputStream localFileInputStream = new FileInputStream(paramString1);
Object localObject1 = null;
try {
    FileOutputStream localFileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(paramString2);
    Object localObject2 = null;
    try {
        GZIPOutputStream localGZIPOutputStream = new GZIPOutputStream(localFileOutputStream);
        Object localObject3 = null;
            try {
                // ... do work
           } catch (Throwable localThrowable6) {
               localObject3 = localThrowable6;
               throw localThrowable6;
           } finally {
               if (localGZIPOutputStream != null) {
                   if (localObject3 != null) {
                       try {
                           localGZIPOutputStream.close();
                       } catch (Throwable localThrowable7) {
                           localObject3.addSuppressed(localThrowable7);
                       }
                   } else {
                       localGZIPOutputStream.close();
                   }
               }
           }
       } catch (Throwable localThrowable4) {
           localObject2 = localThrowable4;
           throw localThrowable4;
       } finally {
           if (localFileOutputStream != null) {
               if (localObject2 != null) {
                   try {
                       localFileOutputStream.close();
                   } catch (Throwable localThrowable8) {
                       localObject2.addSuppressed(localThrowable8);
                   }
               } else {
                   localFileOutputStream.close();
               }
           }
       }
   } catch (Throwable localThrowable2) {
       localObject1 = localThrowable2;
       throw localThrowable2;
   } finally {
       if (localFileInputStream != null) {
           if (localObject1 != null) {
               try {
                   localFileInputStream.close();
               } catch (Throwable localThrowable9) {
                   localObject1.addSuppressed(localThrowable9);
               }
           } else {
               localFileInputStream.close();
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Yes, that is an aweful lot of code, but as you can see it nests each `try`-with-resources block inside the upper one.

Answer (score 2):

What the JLS tries to say is that if you have:

```
try (
   Closable closeable1 = ...;
   Closable closeable2 = ...;
   // ...
   Closable closeablen = ...;
) {
   // ...
}
```

It will get repeatedly decomposed into:

```
try (Closable closeable1 = ...) {
   try (
      Closable closeable2 = ...;
      // ...
      Closable closeablen = ...;
   ) {
      // ...
   }
}
```

And this is repeated for as longer as there are multiple resources in the `try`. This is only an illustration, as I assume it is decomposed into the actual bytecode used for the try-with-resources.

Answer (score 1):

I understand this as the fact that a statement

```
try (
    resource 1
    resource 2
    resource n
) { 
}
```

is translated recursively in `n` statements, the first step being with `n-1` resources in the internal statement :

```
try (
    resource 1
) {

    try ( // n-1 resources here
        resource 2
        resource n
    ) {
    }
 }
```

I agree that the redaction is unclear.